# How to handle ... when final argument is empty?

Tags: r

When using `...` to capture additional arguments, leaving the last argument empty and attempting to use `list(...)` will produce an error

```
f <- function(x, ...) {
    args <- list(...)
}

f(x = 0, y = 10,)


> Error in f(x = 0, y = 10, ) : argument is missing, with no default
```

Here the error message is still informative, but if you pass on the `...` you end up with the following

```
f1 <- function(x, ...) {
    f2(x, ...)
}

f2 <- function(x, ...) {
    list(...)
}

f1(x = 0, y = 10,)

> Error in f2(x, ...) : argument is missing, with no default
```

Now it's very it becomes quite unclear what has gone wrong. Are there idiomatic techniques to capture the error and report it with an useful message?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
f <- function(x, ...) {
    return(
        as.list(substitute(list(...)))[-1]
    )
}

err <- f(x = 0, y = 10,)   #have a closer look --> str(err)

#$`y`
#[1] 10
# 
#[[2]]

fine<- f(x = 0, y = 10)

#$`y`
#[1] 10
```

You see in the Error case you have an empty symbol list element. I believe you can use this information as a hook for your error handling.

---

So your meaningful error handling can look like this:

Thanks to @Roland for joining in.

```
f <- function(x, ...) {
    res <- as.list(substitute(list(...)))[-1]
    if( any(  sapply(res, function(x) { is.symbol(x) && deparse(x) == "" })  ) )  stop('Please remove the the last/tailing comma "," from your input arguments.')
    print("code can run. Hurraa")
}

a <- 0; 
f(x = 0, y = a, hehe = "", "")
#[1] "code can run. Hurraa"

f(x = 0, y = a, hehe = "", "", NULL)
#[1] "code can run. Hurraa"

f(x = 0, y = a, hehe = "", "",)
#Error in f(x = 0, y = a, hehe = "", "", ) : 
#Please remove the the last/tailing comma "," from your input arguments.

f(x = 0, y = a, hehe = "", "", NULL,)
#Error in f(x = 0, y = a, hehe = "", "", NULL, ) : 
#Please remove the the last/tailing comma "," from your input arguments.
```

Comment: Test your approach with `a <- 0; f(x = 0, y = a)`. You need to test for an empty symbol, but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Nice. I wouldn't use it though, because it is slow and this user error is not frequent. Btw., you should use `&&` to avoid unnecessary deparsing.

Comment: well, ... its what OP wants. I can believe he made some sort of UI where users "often" entered a tailing `,` and could not find the error due to a bad posed error message.

Comment: Thanks, users are often novice programmers and this mistake is quite common. The speed cost is negligible compared to the time it saves users and myself, wouldn't put it into anything that runs in high iteration loops but it's perfectly fine for all other usage.